# The updateWalletById controller in the back end is not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mongodb

I have tried creating a controller which will update a specific user's wallet and save it in the database. When i try to fetch it from the postman using the link:
`http://localhost:3001/wallets/{walletID}`  === _id
With the body:

```
{
  "balance": 100
}
```

And it is showing this 400 error as the result:

```
{
    "hasError": true,
    "message": "ERROR: Data Validation Failed.",
    "error": {
        "error": "'walletId' is required. 'balance' is not allowed."
    }
}
```

And when i try to fetch it in another way with this link:
`http://localhost:3001/wallets/{_walletId}` === specific wallet's ID
With the same body, It's showing this 400 status code:

```
{
    "hasError": true,
    "message": "ERROR: Data Validation Failed.",
    "error": {
        "error": "'walletId' contains an invalid value."
    }
}
```

TBH I wasn't expecting it to be working fine because i have tried it once and the code is generated by Chat.gpt. This is the updateWalletById controller:

```
/**
 * this controller updates specific wallet via walletId & returns it
 * @async
 * @param {obj} req - incoming request obj
 * @param {obj} res - outgoing response obj
 * @param {func} next - method to pass control to next request handler in queue
 * @returns updated record from database
 */
const updateWalletById = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const walletId = req.params.walletId; // Fetch walletId from request params
    const balance = req.body.balance; // Fetch balance from request body

    // Update the balance in the database
    const updatedWallet = await Wallet.findByIdAndUpdate(
      walletId,
      { balance },
      { new: true }
    );

    // Check if the wallet was found
    if (!updatedWallet) {
      return res.status(NOT_FOUND).json({
        hasError: true,
        message: 'Wallet not found',
      });
    }

    return res.status(SUCCESS).json({
      hasError: false,
      message: 'Wallet updated successfully',
      data: {
        wallet: updatedWallet,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    logError('ERROR @ updateWalletById -> wallet.controllers.js', error);

    return res.status(SERVER_ERROR).json({
      hasError: true,
      message: 'ERROR: Requested operation failed.',
      error: {
        error: 'An unexpected error occurred on the server.',
      },
    });
  }
};
```

I've understood the functionality and working of the code, and it seems correct but i'm not getting why is it throwing the error?
A help will be so Gratefull <#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the wallets.router.js:

I wasn't passing the `PARAMS` or the `authentication request`.
So, I changed the code from this:

```
// New route to update wallet balance
walletRouter.put(
  `/:walletId`,
  updateWalletById
);
```

To this:

```
// New route to update wallet balance
walletRouter.put(
  `/:walletId`,
  authenticateRequest,
  validateInput(specificWalletSchema, `PARAMS`),
  updateWalletById
);
```